# Upload file on Remote Web Driver with driver type = chromedriver

Tags: karate, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am not able to upload the file when running karate UI automation tests on Docker grid (CI)

Hello,

I am trying to upload a file to perform some of the UI Automation. I am able to upload the file in my local when I am starting a driver with drivertype as chrome. In my organization, we need to run these UI tests as part of CI/CD pipeline. I am running these karate UI automation test cases on a grid docker hosted ineternally with remote webdriver and webdriver session. I was wondering did karate started supporting the file upload for chromedriver as well? If yes, can someone please share the documentation on how to implement.

Comment: Are you validating the developing and container versions?

Comment: No. I am directly calling the grid URL and running UI tests on the grid which is hosted on the cloud.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think `chromedriver` does not support file upload. we invite you and the community to do research and contribute documentation changes if needed